# brctl and virtual interfaces

Tags: linux

Is possible adding a virtual interface to a virtual bridge by `brctl`? Does It make sense? I have a virtual interface but trying to add it to the bridge i get an error: invalid argument.

Thank you all!

Comment: I think you need to explain what you mean by a "virtual interface" before we can answer - do you mean an alias like `eth0:1`? or something else?

Comment: Sorry, maybe you are right...i don't mean an alias interface but a slave interface(for example allocated and registered by `register_netdev` by a lkm) and that is "connected" to a real one(use the real device for transmission)

Comment: So this is an interface provided by a custom kernel module that you have written?

Answer (score 2):

The simple answer seems to be that any "ethernet like" interface can be added to a bridge. So basically is has to use ethernet addressing with MAC address resolution using ARP.

Specifically the `net_device` structure must have a type of `ARPHRD_ETHER` and an `addr_len` of `ETH_ALEN`. It also can't have `IFF_LOOPBACK` or `IFF_DONT_BRIDGE` set.

You can see the code which handles this in `br_add_if()` in `net/bridge/br_if.c` in the kernel source.

Comment: Thanks Tom, i will check all!